# Insert documents into MongoDB only if all fields are unique

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, database

I have the following class structure:

```
public class DBTestItem
{
    public int p0;
    public int p1;
    public int p2;
    public int p3;
    public int p4;
    public int p5;
    public int p6;
    public int p7;
    public string data;
}

public sealed class MongoTestItem : DBTestItem
{
    public ObjectId _id;
}
```

_id is meaningless to me. p0 - p7 represent a composite key, and data represents the value.

I want to save `MongoTestItem` documents where data is unique, and ideally without performing updates as they would be meaningless. In other words, save if data's value does not exist in the collection.

I have looked at the documentation, but can't quite find how to write the statement to meet the above.

I did create a different structure where p0 - p7 makes a composite _id and data is a List, in which case the statement is as follows:

```
var query = Query<MdbData>.EQ(x => x._id, doc._id);
var update = Update<MdbData>.Push(x => x.data, "somenewvalue");
col.Update(query, update, UpdateFlags.Upsert);
```

This has different semantics, so the upsert is OK.

I want to write the above so I can evaluate the performance difference.

Comment: I would personally solve this with a unique compound index on the fields, you can change your primary _id key to contain the composite key but that might effect sharding in a bad way if using that key.

Comment: Fortunately p0 is specifically designed to aid sharding. At this point, I have no idea how to tell Mongo that p0 is the shard key, though. I'll get there :)

Comment: This url http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/sharding/#set-up-a-sharded-cluster contains a section, about half way through talks about sending the command down to tell it to shard on a key. I have no grasp of your scenario and as to the suitability of `p0` for sharding but you sound like you know what your doing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to check if the value of the field 'data' doesn't appear in other documents, you can create a Unique index for `data`.

Or if you want to check the field `data` doesn't exist in that document (when updating), you can use the `$exist` operator with the [Query Builder](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-Referencesandnamespaces)

Answer (score 2):

Are you saying that you want to only insert if "data" is unique? If so, could you create a unique constraint on "data", and update with safeMode ?

I'd also be tempted to structure your composite key like this;

```
db.so.insert(
 {
    _id: {
      p0:1,
      p1:0,
      p2:0,
      p3:0,
      p4:0,
      p5:0,
      p6:0,
      p7:0,
    },
    data:"apiceofdata",
 }
);
```

Comment: That is almost the exact structure I have in my other case, except that data is a collection, so p0-p7 is never duplicated. It's not as fast as what I mention in my question, but having said that, the query I have doesn't check for uniqueness.

Comment: I will take your advice. I already know how to write the query for this. I am curious what the answer to my question is, though.

Comment: by "unique constrains, I meant something like this: db.so.ensureIndex({data:1},{unique:true,sparse:true}); Sorry, did I miss the core of your question? Can you expand?

Comment: I just realized this won't work because there can be many data for a given p0 - p7 set.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean? Or does your solution above cover it?

Comment: I moved data into the _id, which produced exactly what I wanted. So My _id is p0 - p7, data. This way I can have multiple data for a given p0 - p7 set, which provides the constraint I need. I also don't need any manual indexes.