# Insert a document in mongodb only if it does not exist (and no update if it does)

Tags: php, mongodb

I would like to find a way to execute an `insert` in mongodb (using PHP) but only if the document **is not** already in the collection. I could make a query first and find if the document is already in there (and if not perform the insertion) but I would like to make sure there is not a more clever way.

I know that `save` does something like similar to that (insert if _id is not present or update otherwise) but it is not what I am looking for. **I do not want any update going on** if the document is already in the collection.

Anyone has any idea how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Just find it somehow using `$db->collection->find()` method, if there are no result, then do your insert.

Comment: You can create [unique index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/) on your collection. Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046121/insert-documents-into-mongodb-only-if-all-fields-are-unique

Comment: How do you know if the document is in the collection? What do you check?

Comment: You could use the [findAndModify][1] command, but you would basically need the entire document to save it if it doesn't exist, so you should already know if you have a Mongo Id for your data or not, correct?

[1]: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/